# Where is the database installed for git bonobo?

Tags: git, bonobo

I installed git bonobo, and from what I can see, SQL Lite was used as the database. I have a user who's questioning the integrity of the database and says that the passwords aren't secure etc etc., so I wanted to look further into this, but can't even find the location of it.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default connection string specifies DataDirectory, so I would expect to find it in App_Data?